# Input[number] aceitar somente números no Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

Como eu faço para que o campo input[number] aceite somente números no Firefox? No Chrome, Opera e Edge funciona perfeitamente, mas no Firefox o campo[number] aceita letras e espaços.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<input type="number" name="EstoqueProd[]" class="form-control" min="1" value="1"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes forçar isso com um auscultador de eventos do `keydown` que detecta se o caractere inserido é um dígito, comparando o código da tecla.

Um exemplo seria:

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input[name="EstoqueProd[]"]');
input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  var numero = (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105);
  var controlos = [8, 37, 39].includes(e.keyCode);
  if (!numero && !controlos) return e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<input type="number" name="EstoqueProd[]" class="form-control" min="1" value="1" />
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/9unxyknz/1/

Comment: Perfeito Sérgio. Funcionou. Muito obrigado mais uma vez!

Comment: No teclado numérico não funcionou :O

Comment: @DvD bem visto, corrigido.

Comment: Sérgio, o backspace não funciona nessa solução

Comment: @BrenoCosta na verdade nem as setas... cá vai mais um edit :)

Comment: @BrenoCosta corrigido. Obrigado.